# Python doesn't find file

Tags: python, file

I'm learning Python (with Python Crash Course book) and i'm currently working with climate data from the NOAA, but everytime i try to import a file, Python does not find it. I had this error for other programs too and i can't really solve it. Could anyone help me please ?
Here's my code :

```
import csv

filename = 'new-york-weather_60-20.csv'
try :
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header_row = next(reader)
        print(header_row)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"Sorry, the file {filename} does not exist.")
```

Comment: try putting the full path to the file eg `r'C:\My Documents\<file>'` or wherever it may be. If it's not in the same directory as your python script, it won't find it.

Comment: What matters is the current directory of the python kernel, not the directory of the script. You can check that with `import os; os.getcwd()` ("get current working directory"). If the file is located in this directory, it should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know what a *current working directory* is? Do you see that phrase in the book? If you do, please read that section very carefully. Otherwise, try putting the term into a search engine. (To understand the problem: in your own words, where on the hard drive do you think Python should look for this file, and why?)

Comment: Import `os` and put `print(os.listdir('.'))` to see what files are in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python interpreter assumes that the file `'new-york-weather_60-20.csv'` is in the same directory (folder) as where python currently 'is', i.e., the current working directory.

You can see the current working directory by using the `os` module.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

This should be the path in which the `csv` file is located. If it is not, you can either move the file into that same location, or you can move the current working directory to the path where the file is located

```
import os
os.chdir('/the/location/on/your/computer/wherethefileislocated')
filename = 'new-york-weather_60-20.csv'

# You can check if the file is located in this directory
if os.path.exists(filename): # only if this file exists in this location do we continue
    print('The file exists!')
    with open(filename) as f:
       # your code goes here
else:
    print('The file does not exist in this directory')
```

Comment: I had been saving some of my programs in the wrong file and the path was not precise enough i guess. I wrote the right path to the file and it worked. Thank you !